# Having issues closing modal forms with Javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I am having some issues with closing my modal pop-up forms, one of them closes, though the other one does not. I am not really sure where the problem lies, it must be something trivial though. I have just started learning JS seriously, so I'd appreciate some help with it.
I must add that both of the modals open just fine.

```
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("regbtn");

    // Get the modal
    var signinmodal = document.getElementById('signinmodal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var signinbtn = document.getElementById("signinbtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
    signinbtn.onclick = function() {
        signinmodal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target === modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        signinmodal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target === signinmodal) {
            signinmodal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `window.onclick = ...` twice you override the last assignment to it, just like if you would assign a value to a variable:

```
val = 5;
val = 7; // 5 is now gone
```

You should combine them to the same function call to ensure that the events will persist

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target === signinmodal) {
        signinmodal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

The same applies for the span tag

```
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    signinmodal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the solution. I knew I was overriding it, though I didn't really know that you can just easily combine them. I'll definitely keep that in mind for future, Thanks!

Comment: No problem, you could possibly use the [`addEventListener`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) but it's a bit overkill for this specific problem. I'll edit my answer tomorrow and add it as an example though for future reference.